# Is there a way to define a Gurobi environment first and use them again?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gurobi

In other programming languages like `Julia`, we can define a Gurobi environment object first (i.e., `Gurobi.Env()` in `Julia`) and then use them again in solving linear programs.

However, I am not aware of such a feature in `R`. It seems that I need to pull the Gurobi license every time when I call the `gurobi` command in `R`. This cause some troubles when I am running things in parallel on the server because it seems that the Gurobi license is not released immediately after a linear program is solved.

May I know is there a way to define a Gurobi environment object in `R` first and then use them again? Or is there any ways to release the Gurobi license after running a linear program in `R`?

Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the R and the Matlab interfaces of Gurobi do not work as the other object-oriented APIs like Python, C++, or Java. You can only define/build the model and solve it in one go. You would need to use a different API to have more fine-grained control of the environment and the model.